# Downloading to download folder in Android

Tags: android

I have a webview in my app. One of my pages has a link to a mp3 which I should download directly from my app, so using a downloadlistener like this:

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {


            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                    long contentLength) {



              Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
              i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
              startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

is not good for me, because it launches the default browser before actually donwloading the file.

Is there any way I can manage the download myself, to the OS download folder, so that it appears when user goes to the "Downloads" option in the Android menu?

Answer (score 0):

try to do it with an async task like this

mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

```
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
       new MyDowloadTask().execute(url);
        }
    });
```

Where the doInBackground method of your MyDownload task is something like that:

see http://www.androidsnippets.com/download-an-http-file-to-sdcard-with-progress-notification

Comment: I think I might not have stressed the crucial part of my question, I know how to download through an async task, what I want to find out is how to download so that the OS recognizes it as a "Download" itself -- and how to save it to download folder.

Comment: You have to pass the URL of the File as Intent to the native Browser. Thats the best way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may do that by not using DownloadListener. You just have to override onPageFinished of WebViewClient. Check content type if it is "application/octet-stream" .. Then handle downloading thru InputStream. Create the file, save then open. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can download it yourself to the downloads directory requesting the file yourself and storing it into `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);`

Here's some non-functional pseudocode that should help you on your way (but will probably ask you to catch Exceptions and give errors that no network activity may take place on the UI Thread; so you have to embed it in a AsyncTask like Matthew Fisher suggested).

```java
public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
    String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) 
{
    // Define where we want the output file to go
    File fileOut = new File(
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
        "Filename.zip"
    );

    // Request it from the interwebz.
    HttpClient android = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(userAgent);
    HttpResponse fileResponse = android.execute(new HttpGet(url));

    // Write the response to the file
    fileResponse.getEntity().writeTo(new FileOutputStream(fileOut));
}
```